# How to convert CSS subclass to Styled Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to convert my css module to a Styled component but having difficulty with something like this:

```
.table{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.table th {
  background-color: #72a0c1;
  color: white;

  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

In React, my Component would look something like this:

```
function Component() {
  return (
    <table className={styles.table}>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
  );
}
```

If I want to use Styled Components, how can I translate this css code into it. I understand how to create one for the .table rule:

```
const Table = styled.table`
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
`;
```

but the ones I'm having trouble with are the subrules (not sure what the correct term is) like `.table tr:nth-child(even)` or `.table td`. How can I do this easily? Using CSS modules, all I had to do was add the classname to the table element and everything else was handled. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Just create one styled component per tag type then compose the JSX with your own components

Answer (score 0):

Copy the css definition to the styled component. You can use `&` to refer back to the `Table` component. If you put selectors in without the `&`, they will refer to the component's children. In this case you can omite it:

```
const Table = styled.table`

  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  & tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

  & th {
    background-color: #72a0c1;
    color: white;

    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  td { /* without the & will work the same way*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
`;
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k7zxm6?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: you don't need any of these `&` at all.

Comment: @vsync yes if you put selectors in without the ampersand, they will refer to children of the component.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as any regular nested SCSS syntax:

```css
const Table = styled.table`
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

  th {
    background-color: #72a0c1;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }

  td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
`;
```